# Are we able to use passive clause there?

Tags: passive-voice

> I was climbing ladder suddenly, I heard was shouted loudly then my foot
>   slipped and I fell down so broke my leg.

Is that sentence completely true? Are we able to use passive clause there? If not, would you make it with passive!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking about the part that goes **"was shouted loudly"**, then yes, you can use the passive voice, but the sentence is so full of errors that it's complicated to answer.  The most important thing is that you have to hear *something* that was shouted loudly; you can't just "heard shouted loudly".

To simplify it, let's look at just that clause:

> I heard something that was shouted loudly

The subject is *I*, the verb is *heard*, and the object noun phrase is *something that was shouted loudly*.  This is an acceptable use of the passive voice because "something" (the subject) was acted upon ("was shouted loudly") by someone else (who doesn't have to be named, as in any passive construction).

In a phrase like this, we often leave out the "that was", to make it

> I heard something shouted loudly

which is called a [reduced relative clause](https://www.thoughtco.com/reduced-relative-clauses-1211107).